# Radio buttons are not checked initially

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

I have seen a lot of similar questions but none of them could solve my problem:

I have a ng-repeat to show list of items. And each of them has a div which is shown when some condition is met: '`<div ng-if="someCondition"> </div>`

And inside that div, i have a radio button:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="item.Prop" name="published" ng-value="true" ng-checked="item.Prop"> <span>published</span>
<input type="radio" ng-model="item.Prop" name="published" ng-value="false"> <span>not published</span>
```

While other functionalities are working, it is not directly checked when my div becomes visible. However, if i select one of them, it changes its ng-model.

But why is that not selected at the beginning?

Comment: provide your code on plunker

Comment: show more coes how are you looping ng-repeat and model

Comment: I guess `item.Prop` is false?

Comment: some of them is true, some of them false. but non of them is checked. And, i make directly a plunker okay

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/AaNfnbcddprNPAi3eXkZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

The problem was that checkboxes are created for each item in the ng-repeat loop. So, every checkbox has the same name and therefore none of them could be selected.

To solve it, i have just given an unique property of items at the end of the names of checkboxes.

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="item.Prop" name="published{{item.ID}}" ng-value="true" ng-checked="item.Prop"> <span>published</span>
<input type="radio" ng-model="item.Prop" name="published{{item.ID}}" ng-value="false"> <span>not published</span>
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AaNfnbcddprNPAi3eXkZ?p=preview):

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know based on the code you provided, but I'm guessing `item.Prop` is `undefined`. If you provide us with more code, a fiddle or a plunker, we may be able to help more.

Example fiddle demonstrating the behaviour you're experiencing: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20982/

Example fiddle with the checkbox working as you'd wish: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20983/